# CODEIGNITER - Updating multiple rows using checkbox

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have been trying without success to update multiple rows but each time i try i end up getting just a single row updated

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function update()
{
    $data['msg'] = '';
    $id = $_POST['reg_id'];
    $data['students'] = $this->test_model->getStudentData();
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            if (empty($id) || $id==0) {
                $data['msg'] = 'empty';
            } else {
                $userId = "'".implode("', ' ", $id)."'";

                $class =$this->input->post('class');


                $this->test_model->update($userId, $class);


            }


        } 
     $this->load->view('test', $data);
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public function update($where, $data){
    $this->db->query('UPDATE table SET data="'.$data.'" WHERE where IN('.$where.')');

 }
```

**view**

Sorry guys! i have been busy and just had the chance to go through your replies.

Here is the Form view

i have tried out all the solutions i got from you guys but i have not been able to get what i want. perhaps posting the form view would help you guys proffer a better solution

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>test/update" method="POST" >
    <select name="class" id="">
        <option value="some value">some value</option>
        <option value="some value">some value</option>
        <option value="some value">some value</option>
        <option value="some value">some value</option>
        <option value="some value">some value</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>REG. ID</th>
                <th>SURNAME</th>
                <th>FIRST NAME</th>
                <th>MIDDLE NAME</th>
                <th>CLASS</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

    <?php foreach ($students as $key): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="reg_id[]" value="<?php echo $key->reg_id ?>"><?php echo $key->reg_id ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->first_name ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->last_name ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->mid_name ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->class ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
        </tbody>
    </table><br>


</form>
```

Comment: So, obviously `$id` is not an array. Did you output `$id` contents?

Comment: Also, you are using `update_student_class` but show us `update` from model, are they the same?

Comment: the output shows it is an array but still updates only one record

Comment: I would like to see the form's view code for a better understanding of the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions about what you want to achieve but, if I understand correctly, I think this is what you're looking for.

**controller**

```
public function update()
{
    $data['msg'] = 'empty';
    $data['students'] = $this->test_model->getStudentData();

    if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $id_list = $this->input->post('reg_id');
        if($id_list) //were any checkboxes posted?
        {
            $data['msg'] = '';
            $class = $this->input->post('class');
            if($class)  //make sure it was posted
            {
                $this->test_model->update($id_list, $class);
            }
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('test', $data);
}
```

The model uses [update_batch()](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::update_batch)

**Model**

```
public function update($id_list, $data)
{
    foreach($id_list as $id)
    {
        $update_data[] = ['where' => $id, 'data' => $data,];
    }

    if(isset($update_data))
    {
        $this->db->update_batch('table', $update_data, 'where');
    }
}
```

Comment: i got following error messages: One or more rows submitted for batch updating is missing the specified index

Answer (score 0):

In your query you missed to pass the column name in the query.
When you use IN keyword then the database column name must required before IN keyword.

For Example: UPDATE table_name SET name='abcd' WHERE id IN('2,3,5');

This will update the record number 2, 3 and 5.

Try the below code in your model. Add your database column name in the query.

```
public function update($where, $data){
$this->db->query('UPDATE table SET data="'.$data.'" WHERE where id IN('.$where.')'); 

}
```